# SQL Function saved in field - how to execute DATEADD()?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a string column field named FunctionValue.
This field can contain either `DATEADD(datepart, number, date)` or `GETDATE()`, or something else.

If for example it's `DATEADD(year, 3, GETDATE())`
I want this later to be executed during a SP runtime and the value saved in a variable called `@FunctionValue`.

```
SET @FunctionValue = ( SELECT CASE
                        WHEN FunctionValue LIKE 'DATEADD%' THEN --???
                        WHEN FunctionValue LIKE 'GETDATE' THEN CAST(GETDATE() AS nvarchar(255))
                        ELSE FunctionValue
                    END AS FV
                    FROM @TSV_WithTarget
```

I'm not sure what I'd need to put there to make it so that whatever the value is, the result of the `DATEADD` function is returned and saved in `@FunctionValue`.

Comment: You can't parameterize the 1st argument - the date interval - of `DATEADD`. So at the very least, you'd need a large case expression for all of the possibilities - 13 (or 35 if you support all of the abbreviations)

Comment: To add to what @Damien_The_Unbeliever is saying, you'd also have to evaluate the 3rd argument, so it seems you cannot escape running part of this as UN-parameterized dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way;

```
--modify field or add an assignment
declare @sql nvarchar(128) = 'set @result = ' + 'DATEADD(year, 3, GETDATE())'

declare @FunctionValue datetime
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@result datetime output', @FunctionValue output

select @FunctionValue
```

The type is needed in advance, or you could do something ugly like explicitly casting to sql_variant.

Comment: The `DATEADD(year, 3, GETDATE())` was just an example value.

Comment: Mine was an example as well, `declare @sql nvarchar(128) = 'set @result = ' + (select FunctionValue FROM @TSV_WithTarget)` (assuming one row)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @FunctionValue NVARCHAR(500)
SELECT @FunctionValue = 'SELECT ' + ( 
                            SELECT CASE
                                WHEN FunctionValue LIKE 'DATEADD%' THEN 'DATEADD(year, 3, GETDATE())'
                                WHEN FunctionValue LIKE 'GETDATE' THEN 'GETDATE()'
                                ELSE FunctionValue
                            END
                            FROM @TSV_WithTarget
                        )

EXEC sp_executesql @FunctionValue
```